# Intent with Countdown crashes android app

Tags: android, android-intent, countdown

My Android app crashes when it reaches `countdown` `0`. Below is the part of code related to it.

```
final CountDownTimer countdown=new CountDownTimer(60000, 1000){

         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) 
         {
             tvTime.setText((millisUntilFinished / 1000)+"'s");
         }

         public void onFinish()
         {
             try{

                 tvTime.setText("Time Over");
                 this.cancel();
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Answer: "+ OriginalWord, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                
                 Intent i=new Intent(LastJumble.this,ScoreCard.class);
                 i.putExtra("username",username);
                 i.putExtra("totalQues", totalQues);
                 i.putExtra("count", count);
                 startActivity(i);               

             }
             catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }

      }
}.start();
```

Comment: pls upload crash log

Answer (score 3):

`this.cancel()` will try to cancel the CountDownTimer.  Since the timer is finished this will break.  If you mean to call a cancel method in your outer class you should reference it as `OuterClass.this.cancel()` where OuterClass is the name of the class.